# Tips on getting docker to work without having to run `sudo docker -d` on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, service, docker, daemon

After upgrading my system from 14.10 to 15.04 I can't seem to use docker like I used to. I already have a docker group that my user is part of and I used to be able to use docker without sudo just fine. Now I can't use it unless I have `sudo docker -d` running in another terminal. Simply running `docker ps` gives me this error:

`FATA[0000] Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.18/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?`

I've tried reinstalling, rebooting, restarting services, and blowing out configurations to no avail. Any tips would be appreciated. As a side note, I installing 15.04 in a vm to see if I could get docker working there and I was able to set it up no problem. seems like an issue specific to those who have upgraded from 14.10.

Comment: Since it is related to a new Ubuntu release, this should have been asked on http://askubuntu.com or on any docker forum, maybe on serverfault.com.

Comment: ubuntu 15.04 switched from upstart to systemd - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers - that is why docker service is not started automatically.

Comment: @Alexander, good point, I'll go ahead and look into those forumns.

Comment: @ISanych, that's what I thought too, however even when I set up the service through systemctl it doesn't work.

Comment: @haymez Is there anything in the journalctl logs regarding the service?

Comment: A relevant (I think) bug report https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12002

Comment: @Gigablah not sure, I ended up doing a clean install of ubuntu and that seemed to fix it. It was a very odd issue and it seemed like it may have been an issue more specific with my upgrade.. Regardless, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29936914/2576959) answer will probly help most coming to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did u checked this http://docs.docker.com/articles/systemd/? This helped me to start docker under Ubunu 15.04.

Comment: Links tend to change or go missing, could you explain some of the contents or quote it here?

Comment: the link works for me, by this command "sudo systemctl enable docker" make docker service start at boot.

Comment: After I did a clean install of Ubuntu  this worked for me. However what's odd is that these steps didn't work for me after my initial upgrade to 15.04. Even when I wiped out my docker install and started over.. Very odd.

Answer (score 1):

What to do if this fails...

```
$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

..and you have added user to docker group and Ubuntu still requires sudo:

If you initially ran Docker CLI commands using sudo before adding your user to the docker group, you may see the following error, which indicates that your `~/.docker/` directory was created with incorrect permissions due to the sudo commands.

To fix this problem, either remove the `~/.docker/` directory (it is recreated automatically, but any custom settings are lost), or change its ownership and permissions using the following commands:

```
$ sudo chown "$USER":"$USER" /home/"$USER"/.docker -R

$ sudo chmod g+rwx "$HOME/.docker" -R
```

Answer (score 0):

What the link mafahand provided tells is how to use docker on a systemd based host. Ubuntu 15.04 uses systemd now while older version used upstart. That might explain why upgraded systems show erratic behavior. Check out [the Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers) for some help on that regard.

After installing docker via

```
sudo apt install docker.io
```

you might have to reboot your system or start the docker.socket unit manually. For some reason that did not happen on my machine after installing it.

Type

```
systemctl status docker
```

to check whether docker is up and running. If it is not enabled use

```
sudo systemctl enable docker
```

to enable it permanently and/or

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

to run the service.